# How to get list of room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How to get list of room in socket.io in latest version (v1.3.7) ?

```
io.nsps['/namespace'].adapter.rooms
```

Will return something like this:

```
{ 
  mIfp3VIpt103xS3RAAAD: { mIfp3VIpt103xS3RAAAD: true },
  '9XaViM2Q-A1NGziRAAAE': { '9XaViM2Q-A1NGziRAAAE': true },
  science: { '9XaViM2Q-A1NGziRAAAE': true },
  '2FopECkAq5Z4AIHMAAAF': { '2FopECkAq5Z4AIHMAAAF': true },
  math: { '2FopECkAq5Z4AIHMAAAF': true },
  s3JRFhNUz1Tz9apeAAAH: { s3JRFhNUz1Tz9apeAAAH: true } 
}
```

Obviously the only rooms in there was `science` and `math`.
I suspect the others are socket id.

How can i only get `science` and `math` as a room list?

Answer (score 1):

Socket.io will keep an opened room per connected socket, so that sending a message to a single sockets works: 
`socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('my message', msg)`

You could keep a list of connected sockets id's:

```
var cached = []
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    if(cached.indexOf(socket.id) === -1)
       cached.push(socket.id)
})
```

*Don't forget to remove them on socket disconnection*

Then, reduce the list of rooms:

```
var rooms = io.nsps['/namespace'].adapter.rooms
var realRooms = {}
for(var i in rooms) {
   if(~cached.indexOf(i)) {
        realRooms[i] = rooms[i]
   }
}
```

There might be other ways of doing this but this is the first I think of.

Comment: what is this `~` symbol for?

Comment: It's the bitwise `NOT` operator, [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). Basically `~(-1)` becomes `0`, and will be evaluated as `false`. My condition becomes: if `i` not in the cached array (`indexOf` is `-1`), it's a room. See @slier answer, `io.nsps['/chatSystem'].adapter.sids` is an object containing the different socket id's.

Comment: oh it's yourself (the same that asked the question), my bad ^^.

Answer (score 1):

Since `io.nsps['/chatSystem'].adapter.sids` will return collection of connected socket, this is how i solve the problem

```
var realRooms = [];
var rooms = io.nsps['/chatSystem'].adapter.rooms;
var sids = io.nsps['/chatSystem'].adapter.sids;

for ( var room in rooms ) {
    if ( !( room in sids ) ) {
          realRooms.push( room );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the list of ROOMS (different to id of each socket/connection) with:

```
for(R in io.nsps)console.log(R);
```

this return list of each ROOM in your server/machine.

(nsps is "internal name" of each Namespace)